# Passing a non-empty string to snprintf causes an unrelated char* array to change addresses

Tags: c, string, stdio

I'm working on the exercises in K&R's book, and I've run into a weird bug while trying to extend 04-06 to allow for variables with string names. Truthfully, I've actually managed to fix the bug (pretty simple - explained below), but I'd like to know why the error was occuring in the first place.

For those unfamiliar with the problem, you're basically asked to create a command-line calculator (using Polish notation) that can store and recall variables with character names.

Here's the relevant code where the issue occurs:

```
#define MAXOPLEN 1000

int varCount = 1;
char **keys;
char **values;
// changing the declaration to:
// char strOps[][STROPCOUNT] = { ... };
// fixed the issue
char *strOps[STROPCOUNT] = { "dupe", "swap", "del", "print",
                             "clr", "sin", "cos", "tan",
                             "exp", "pow", "ln", "log",
                             "mem", "re"};

main() {
    keys = malloc(varCount * sizeof(char[MAXOPLEN]));
    keys[0] = "ans";
    values = malloc(varCount * sizeof(char[MAXOPLEN]));
    values[0] = "0.0";

    ... // Other stuff related to the program
}

// flag is unrelated to the problem I'm asking about. It just checks to see
// if the variable name used to store value n is 'ans', which is where
// the last returned value is stored automatically
void memorize(char s[], double n, bool flag) {
    ...  // small conditional block for flag

    for (i = 0; i < varCount; i++) {
        if (equals(keys[i], s)) {
            found = True;
            // Next line is where the program actually breaks
            snprintf(values[i], MAXOPLEN, "%f", n);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!found) {
        i = varCount;
        varCount++;

        keys = realloc(keys, varCount * sizeof(char*));
        keys[i] = malloc(sizeof(char[MAXOPLEN]));
        keys[i] = s;

        values = realloc(values, varCount * sizeof(char*));
        values[i] = malloc(sizeof(char[MAXOPLEN]));
        snprintf(values[i], MAXOPLEN, "%f", n);
    }
}
```

After compiling and running, the first time you enter in an equation to calculate, everything seems to run smoothly. However, while debugging, I found out that the first three char* in strOps were oddly made to point to different addresses. When trying to save the return value of the equation to "ans", it enters the for-loop in memorize() that tries to see if string s had been used as a key name already. It correctly finds keys[0] to point to a string matching s's value ("ans"), then attempts to convert double n to a string and save it in values[0].

While inside the snprintf() function, the first three char* in strOps are made to point elsewhere inside this method in corecrt_stdio_config.h:

```
_Check_return_ _Ret_notnull_
__declspec(noinline) __inline unsigned __int64* __CRTDECL __local_stdio_printf_options(void)
{
    // Error occurs after this next line:
    static unsigned __int64 _OptionsStorage;
    return &_OptionsStorage;
}
```

As commented in the code above, making strOps a 2D array of characters (rather than an array of char pointers) fixed the issue. This makes sense because arrays of characters can't have the values of individual characters changed, but what I don't understand is why the that method in corecrt_stdio_config.h was changing the values of those three pointers in the first place.

Thanks!

Comment: Start using correct prototype function declarators. `main()` is deprecated. And use a more recent Book, K&R is long time outdated. It does not teach modern C! And see [ask], provide a [mcve]. Even iff your code compiled without warnings, it does not make sense.

Comment: And check the result of functions if they are relevant for further execution! `realloc` might fail!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initializations are incorrect and are causing the change:

```
keys[0] = "ans";
values[0] = "0.0";
```

Both `"ans"` and `"0.0"` are *string literals* and cannot be used to initialize the arrays, you need to use `strcpy` after you allocate.

```
strcpy (keys, "ans");
strcpy (values, "0.0");
```

Your other option is to assign one character at a time:

```
size_t i;
char *p = "ans";
for (i = 0; i < strlen (p); i++)
    keys[i] = p[i];                 /* copy to keys */
p[i] = 0;                           /* nul-terminate */
```

**note:** these are examples of your errors, you do the same thing throughout your code.

Comment: Could you explain a bit about what happens when you try to do

    keys[0] = "ans";

?

Comment: `strOps` is an array of pointers, initialized to the list of string literals. `keys` is a *pointer-to-pointer-to char*. When you allocate `keys` you create a block of memory `varCount * sizeof(char[MAXOPLEN])` (which is `1000` bytes, enough for `~125 uninitialized pointers`). When you assign `keys[0] = "ans";`, you are assigning the address for `"ans"` (in read only memory) to the first pointer in `keys`. When you then attempt to access `keys` as a *pointer-to-char* it appears the address for `keys` has changed (because the *address of an array* is the *address of the first element*).

Comment: That makes sense. Why did later changing the value of keys[0] change the first three pointers in strOps though? As far as I can tell, they're not related in any way.

Comment: Well, later changing `keys[0]` didn't change the first 3 pointers in `strOps` *per-se*, it changed where the first 3 pointers in `strOps` were pointing. Since `"dupe", "swap", ...` are in *read-only* memory they cannot be changed, howerver you can change where `strOps[0], strOps[1], ...` point. I would need the rest of your code to point out where, but that is about 100% the issue. To add a code block to a comment, simply place the code between `backticks` (e.g. `\`...\``)